# Economics optimisation

Tags: optimization, economics

I have an economics question, which i want to solve mathematically. Two countries produce 2 identical goods. They both can allocate a different percentages of overall production towards each good a and b (eg. 90% a and 10% b).

Country S can produce 10a or 6b if they allocate 100% production towards one.

Similarly, country T can produce 5a or 2b.

I am trying to calculate the greatest overall output between these two countries for a and b for both goods. Overall production of a should exceed 7.5 while overall production of b should exceed 4.

This has led to the following equations, where x and y are the percentage allocation of production allocated to each good:

x10a +y5a > 7.5

(1-x)6b + (1-y)2b > 4

I have attempted to solve this problem, but so far have found nothing.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y$ be the percentages of overall production towards good $A$ practiced in countries $S$ and $T$, respectively. The overall output is given by $f(x,y)=10 x + 6(1-x) + 5y + 2(1-y) = 4x + 3y +8$, and the production restrictions are $10 x+5y \ge 7.5, \quad 6(1-x) + 2 (1-y)  \ge 4$. So, you  want to solve the problem
\begin{align*}
\max & f(x,y)=4x+3y+8\\
\textrm{s.t.}\,\,  & 10 x+ 5y \ge 7.5\\
& 6x + 2y \leq 4\\
& 0 \leq x,y \leq 1
\end{align*}

Can you solve it now? The final solution is $x=\frac 13, y = 1$, i.e. country S should allocate $1/3$ of resources to the production of $A$ and $2/3$ to the production of $B$, while country $T$ should allocate all resources to the production of $A$.

[edited: the second restriction was wrong]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking for maximum output, so a single value for x and y which gives the greatest overall amount of good a and b. Although now that i look at it, it doesn't seem possible to solve for said values. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There needs to be over 5 units of b, and 8.5 units of a produced overall. thus allocating all production towards good a would not work.

Comment: @PavanSubburaj the restriction relative to good A was not correct, I will edit the post.